# How to avoid backslashes in JSON returned from PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having some trouble with the code below. the console log returns:

```
"returningList{"view":0,"new":1,"random":1} result: "{\"view\":0,\"new\":1,\"random\":1}""
```

As you can see it's acquiring backslashes that make it no longer JSON, despite specifying `datatype : 'json'`.

The problem seems to be occurring where the result is read back in from PHP to javascript, because if I write `$jsonArr` to MySQL before echoing it then the SQL data shows the correct string (i.e. without the backslashes).

Please help because this apparent insanity is really winding me up. All I want to do is get my data back – In my actual code I don't normally return the JSON I passed in as data, but here it suffices to prove the point. I thought that the `'json'` datatype would mean that it would accept echoed JSON without corrupting it.

Apologies for the following bluntness, but in response to similar questions I've seen people just say "it escapes the quotes", as if that that answers the question – in this case at least it seems that it doesn't: Obviously (AFAIK) that's where the backslashes are coming from, but the quotes are part of the JSON syntax (which it knows it's expecting), not part of the field content, so they clearly shouldn't be escaped. I need a **solution** please. Thanks.

```
window.newGot = listBuild({
    'view' : 0,
    'new' : 1,
    'random' : 1
});

function listBuild(options)
    //Fill the new list.
    return $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "./php/getList.php",
        cache : false,
        data : {
            options : JSON.stringify(options)
        },
        datatype : "json"
    }).then(function(jsonList) {
        console.log('returningList' + JSON.stringify(options) + ' result: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonList));
        return jsonList;
    });
}
```

Here's the php file contents:

```
<?php
$options = json_decode($_POST['options'], true);
$jsonArr = json_encode($options);
echo $jsonArr;
```

Comment: The slashes shouldn't cause any issues, it's quite normal as far as I know ?

Comment: Why are you passing JSON as a string to `data` and then decoding it on the serverside, makes no sense ?

Comment: @adeneo - I'm also a little confused why you're handling the data is that sense as well - are you not able to leave it as an object and allow the AJAX function to handle the conversions?

Comment: Can't you just pass "options" as the object and not call `JSON.stringify(options)`?

Comment: All was not as it seemed to me:

Firstly using datatype : 'json' doesn't seem to produce an object. It produces a string that is correctly formatted to be parsed into an object (using JSON.parse for instance). This is directly contrary to the online description of the API, so it's no surprise that I was confused, unless I'm still confused, which is possible. If someone could confirm that I'm correct then I'll repost this as an answer.

Secondly the backslashes aren't therefore the reason that I have a problem with the result. As @adeneo pointed out they don't seem to be a problem at all.

Comment: Using `json` as a dataType  should return a javascript object that is already parsed without having to use JSON.parse.

Comment: I know that it should. I was hoping someone could confirm either that it can but that I'm not doing it right, or that it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Whatever's generating the JSON is probably double-encoding, e.g.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($data as $foo) {
    $arr[] = json_encode($foo);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

JSON-encoding should be the very last step performed, just before the output to the client occurs.

e.g.

```
$foo = 'This is a string';
$foo_step1 = json_encode($foo); // "This is a string"
$foo_step2 = json_encode($foo_step1); // "\"This is a string\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the issue is, it might be because you are using json.stringify, have you tried parsing it as json instead?

Jquery has the following if you include the jquery library, otherwise the browser has one as well:
$.parseJSON()

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

The other issues could be that you are double encoding it

Also run it through a validator, that is not valid code

http://jsonlint.com/

"returningList{"view":0,"new":1,"random":1} result: "{\"view\":0,\"new\":1,\"random\":1}""

This is what I would expect the json to look like

```
{
"returningList": {
    "view": 0,
    "new": 1,
    "random": 1
},
"result": {
    "view": 0,
    "new": 1,
    "random": 1
}
```

}

Comment: Re "that is not valid code" what is not valid code? Please don't confuse the console output I've generated with the result I want from the echo or the return. The console output is for debugging and any similarity to something that may be a valid anything is purely coincidental.

Comment: Sorry – I meant any similarity of (literally) the-whole-console-output to valid JSON is coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `jsonList` is the JSON string, not the decoded object that it represents. So when you call `JSON.stringify()` on it, you're re-encoding the string.

When you specify `dataType: 'json'`, jQuery is supposed to decode the response automatically. I know it does this when you specify the callback in the `success:` option, but it looks like it doesn't do it when you use `.then()`. Try using `.done()` instead.

With that said, I tried to reproduce your result at jsfiddle, and couldn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/53jthkyu/4/